# ordered split of spark dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a sql.DataFrame in spark and I want to split it with scala into train and test dataframes.
I am using this code right now:

```
val Array(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
```

but I dont want to split my dataframe randomly. What I want is to get first 70% of it as train and the rest as test. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: as spark is distributed thing, there is no such thing as 'first' and 'last'.

Comment: Is it the timeseries data? and do we have any `eventTIme` to decide the sequence of events, if yes then we can

Comment: I have an incremental id for each row. Does it do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `id` column is monotonic, and you know min/max values (or can find them, using something like `df.agg(min(col("id")), max(col("id")).collect()`), then you can simply find your "split value", like `(maxValue - minValue) * 0.7 + minValue` (if I'm not mistaken). Then you can split df into to with filter:

```scala
val train = df.filter(col("id") < lit(splitValue))
val test =  df.filter(col("id") > lit(splitValue))
```

Comment: monotonical does not assure that are contiguous values. I am curious about the formula. becuase I am not sure how it works in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Piggybacking on @rayan-ral 's answer - alternatively, if you want Spark itself to figure out min/max for `id` column, you can [repartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#repartitionByRange-int-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-) your dataset **by range** into `N` partitions, and then take `0.7 * N` *partitions* to be your training set.

```
df = df.repartitionByRange(100,col("id"))
val train = df.filter(spark_partition_id() < 70)
```